# syntax for JS arrow function as an object method

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, object-literal

1st time question here.

I found this useful function by @CertainPerformance for recursively finding nested items by ID.

```
const findItemNested = (arr, itemId, nestingKey) => (
  arr.reduce((a, item) => { 
    if (a) return a;
    if (item.id === itemId) return item;
    if (item[nestingKey]) return findItemNested(item[nestingKey], itemId, nestingKey)
  }, null)
);
```

I can't figure out the syntax for making this function a method on a 'util' object. The following syntax doesn't work:

```
var util = {
const findItemNested = (arr, itemId, nestingKey) => (
  arr.reduce((a, item) => { 
    if (a) return a;
    if (item.id === itemId) return item;
    if (item[nestingKey]) return findItemNested(item[nestingKey], itemId, nestingKey)
  }, null)
);
}
```

The syntax needs to be something like this as far as I know:

```
var util = {
findItemNested: function (arr, itemId, nestingKey) => (
  arr.reduce((a, item) => { 
    if (a) return a;
    if (item.id === itemId) return item;
    if (item[nestingKey]) return findItemNested(item[nestingKey], itemId, nestingKey)
  }, null)
);
}
```

But this syntax doesn't work of course. I tried backing out the arrow function syntax into normal function syntax as follows (note that I have changed the parentheses needed for an arrow function to return an object literal to curly braces in order to match the needed syntax for a method on an object).

```
var util = {
findItemNested: function (arr, itemId, nestingKey) => {
  arr.reduce((a, item) => { 
    if (a) return a;
    if (item.id === itemId) return item;
    if (item[nestingKey]) return findItemNested(item[nestingKey], itemId, nestingKey)
  }, null)
}
}
```

However, while there isn't a compile or runtime error, this syntax results in the function returning undefined rather than finding a nested item that exists.

The only way I can get this function to work, is to have it set as a globally available function with the original syntax from @CertainPerformance in my script.js file.

Is there a way to get this function into my var util? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `function (arr, itemId, nestingKey) => {` remove the `=>`. Also, you shouldn't have `;` after the method inside the object literal.

Comment: The recursive call must become a method call: `util.findItemNested(…)` or `this.findItemNested(…)`

Answer (score 0):

You are using es6 arrow fuctions along with the `function` keyword. If you want this to work inside a object, the best way is to keep your code the same, but delete the arrow. Your second line should look like this:

```
findItemNested: function (arr, itemId, nestingKey){
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use an arrow function syntax here, but more a [method syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions):

```
const util = {
  findItemNested(arr, itemId, nestingKey) {
    return arr.reduce((a, item) => { 
      if (a) return a;
      if (item.id === itemId) return item;
      if (item[nestingKey]) return util.findItemNested(item[nestingKey], itemId, nestingKey)
    }, null)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for answers and suggestions.

I have tried again to implement the code as follows using the function keyword so as to have it be a method on my var util as follows:

```
var util = {

  findItemNested: function (arr, itemId, nestingKey) {
    arr.reduce((a, item) => {
      if (a) return a;
      if (item.id === itemId) return item;
      if (item[nestingKey]) return this.findItemNested(item[nestingKey], itemId, nestingKey)
    }, null)
  },
}
```

And as Bergey suggested above, I have made the recursive call into a method call with:

```
this.findItemNested(…)
```

Unfortunately, the method still returns undefined when structured this way. The stand-alone global function version as originally posted as an answer by @CertainPerformance in another stackoverflow question is the only way I can get it to work. Any other ideas about what I might be doing wrong here? Thanks again.